# About the functional inverse of integrals and infinite products.

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, inverse, infinite-product, elementary-functions

It seems $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ are the only entire functions, that are the functional inverse of an integral of some elementary function $f(x)$ , such that they have a simple infinite product representation. Is that true ? Why ? Is $\prod (1-\frac{x^3}{n^3})$ or $\prod(1-\frac{x^4}{n^4})$ a counterexample ?

Comment: Except $x$ maybe.

Comment: Infinite product for $x$ ? Hmm maybe. But not intresting. Right?

Comment: Define interesting.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Well, $x \cdot 1 \cdot 1 ...$ is not.

Comment: $f(x)$ not a polynomial = intresting. I think.

Comment: What happens with $\cos(x^3)$?

Comment: How do you write $arccos(x)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ as an integral ?

Comment: The integral of its derivative, which is elementary as the derivative of any elementary function. If the functions you are looking for are elementary, so are its inverses, and also the derivatives of its inverses.

Comment: @Franklin.vp: "so are its inverses": Inverses of elementary functions need not be elementary. (I agree with the first part of your comment.)